# pandas read_csv convert column to type int

Tags: python, pandas

I downloaded a csv and when I read the data, it printed out the `'Volume'` column as:

```
0     623,446,600
1     371,965,300
2     260,752,300
3     116,561,400
Name: Volume, dtype: object
```

How do I change it to be `dtype: int` instead?

I tried to replace the `,` but i'm not sure how it's done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need parameter `thousands=','` in [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html).

Sample:

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas.compat import StringIO

temp=u"""Volume
0;623,446,600
1;371,965,300
2;260,752,300
3;116,561,400
"""
#after testing replace 'StringIO(temp)' to 'filename.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(temp), sep=";", thousands=',')
print (df)
      Volume
0  623446600
1  371965300
2  260752300
3  116561400

print (df.dtypes)
Volume    int64
dtype: object
```

Comment: Oh. That was easy. Thank you!